# Undefined Variable, Undefined Index - not solved using using global $var

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a PHP function which displays results from a database, using a few different variables.

On the PHP Script, I have declared the variables when declaring the function, like so:

```
function printResults ($row, $result)
```

and when I have used

```
require('includes/script.php'); 

printResults($row, $result);
```

I still get an error saying

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: row

I have tried other suggestions like using "global $row" however this doesn't solve the issue, it's my first time using functions so its thrown me off.

Here is the script with the function in:

```
$query = "SELECT title,description FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);

function printResults ($row, $result) {
    if($result) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<div>'.$row['title'].'</div>';;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any declaration of $row. You only need to pass the result to the function.

Comment: i don't think you can print $row before defining it

Comment: When you use the $row variable in the function CALL, there is no $row variable defined. And more important. Is the error declare to be in "script.php" or in the main php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass this $row variable, it gets defined inside the function.

```
$query = "SELECT title,description FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);

function printResults ($result) {
    if($result) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<div>'.$row['title'].'</div>';;   
        }
    }
}   
printResults($result);
```

Comment: I have removed the variable from the function declaration as well as the page where the function is ran from, however the title from the query which was appearing is no longer, how would I fix this?